# How to update the title of audio file through its attachment metadata

Tags: attachments, post-meta, audio

I am trying to programmatically update some metadata of audio file attached to a post. I have been able to update the artist and album properties of the audio file but title doesn't stick. I can go through media library and edit the title and it works but not through backend. Can you please assist? Here's how I do so now:

```
              $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment->ID, false);

              $meta = array (
             'artist' => $mainArtist,
                     'title' => $TitleAndFeaturedArtist,
             'album' => ' ',
                            );

                    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment->ID, $meta);
```

The artist and album gets updated but not title. Title seems to be coming from the iD3 tag but through media library in wordpress, you can edit and set yours. I am trying to avoid manually processing over 2000 files. There has to be a way :(

Please help. Any suggestions or alternative would help

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. It's because the title isn't part of the attachment metadata technically. The audio attachment itself is stored in the database as a post with a post type of attachement and applicable mime type. To update the title of the audio is to update the post title